# Removing hash tag and comment notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with 54 thousand lines and it's taking a long time to do by hand. It's a host file that goes on our workstations replacing the existing one to block out bad sites but I am going to import it into our web filter. The web filter doesn't accept symbols or any special characters it has to be siteaddress.com so I need to edit this file manually.

It looks something like this and there are a lot of commented out lines. What is the search expression I would use to remove the hash and the comment/text after that with nothing.

```
    # [hosted on cloudfront]
 d3anogn3pbtk4v.cloudfront.net
 d3oltyb66oj2v8.cloudfront.net
 d2bgg7rjywcwsy.cloudfront.net

# [vserv.mobi]
 ad.leadboltapps.net  ## another airpush style ad#
 i.tapit.com
 cdn1.crispadvertising.com
# [General]
 lb.usemaxserver.de
 tracking.klickthru.com
 www.the-best-movies.xcc24.pl
 wydawca.lead.network
# End KADhosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has a regex option for it's find / replace screen

[image]

You can then enter a regular expression to search and replace for your comments.

For me (using Notepad++ 7.5.1), the pattern `#(.+)` works as long as the **. matches newline** checkbox in *unchecked*. If you just replace it the matches with some sort of white spaces character, it should do what you want.

As user @PaulJ pointed out the following expressinon matches jsut as well, but is probably a bit cleaner than my original `#\s*\[.+?\].*\r\n`

Comment: I did try this but it highlights all text starting where the first # starts. I think this is because there are extra spaces all over. Not sure if I am allowed to link anything but if you google "stevenblack hosts" on github should be first results. The hosts file there is what I am working with

Comment: @Ron I'm going to edit my answer. It seems to work for me if I remove that escaped newline, uncheck the **. matches newline** and just use the pattern: `#(.+)`

Comment: If there are spaces in front of some of the `#` you can do: `\s*#.+`.  I don't think you'll need `(.+)` as it is for capturing the input.  That being said I'm not super familiar with notepad++ regular expressions.  If you want to make it more exact you can try: `\s*\[.+?\].*\n` which matches: Zero or more spaces, one [, any number of characters followed by one ], zero or more characters followed by a carriage return, if you're on windows you may need to do `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @PaulJ that seems to be better than mine if you include `#` like `#\s*\[.+?\].*\r\n`. Do you mind if I edit that in?

Comment: @earwig this worked #(.+) thank you the extra lines and space I can take out thank you all for the help